# What is the best way to monitor RavenDB health?

Tags: ravendb

Is there good well known practice for RavenDB to check the availability of RavenDb or check to see how overloaded it is at any given time? I looked into some ravendb API service. Did not seem to find one on health monitoring. Is there like official ravendb tool or something that might accomplish what I am looking for?

Comment: This question doesn't fit the [criteria for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).  But you may want to look at [RavenDB's Performance Counters](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/administration/perf-counters).

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [statistics endpoint](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/server/administration/statistics) which I think is as close as RavenDB gets to what you're asking. For true health monitoring you might want to roll your own solution which wraps the statistics endpoint with IIS monitoring.